# make modules_install get error target is not a directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

I'm trying to install linux-3.14.63 kernel to ubuntu.

It worked well until I compiled with 'sudo make' command.

but I get error when I try 'sudo make modules_install'.

```
ln: target '/source' is not a directory
make: *** [_modinst_] Error 1
```

I'm new to os.... so I have no idea how to fix this

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: SO is for programming.

Comment: Check that absolute path to kernel sources doesn't contain spaces and other special symbols.